# Selenium script does not run in Firefox when run as sudo

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have following simple script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.google.com')

browser.quit()
```

When I run this script with normal user as `python3 test.py` it executes correctly. But when I run this script as root user `sudo python3 test.py`, it exits with following error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process`

There's a requirement which needs the script to be executed as root user. What should I do to incorporate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in headless mode

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, I don't want to run this in headless mode. I specifically want to see the GUI.